# “Black skin” Vs. “Black-skinned” Vs. “with black skin”?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, adjectives

Are all these expressions correct?

- 1) A person with black skin
- 2) A black-skinned person
- 3) A black skin person
- 4) A person skinned with black
- 5) A person skinned black
- 6) A person of black skin

Comment: Please explain which ones you think might or might not be correct, and why.  Otherwise this is a sensitive subject, and acceptable verbiage changes.  You should probably copy what you have read in recent media.

Comment: #3, #4, and #5 are not  idiomatic ways of stating that the person is from a race whose members have black skin.

Answer (score 1):

#1 and #2 are the normal way to say this. You could also say simply "a black person". In context, this is understood to mean that his skin is black and not his hair or his teeth or whatever.

We definitely don't say "skinned with black". To "skin" a person or animal is to cut and peel the skin off. It's what you might do to an animal after you have killed it and before cooking it to eat, or what you might do to a person as a horrible form of torture.

"A black-skinned person" would arguably be grammatically correct, but no one says that. We say "a black-haired person", "a light-colored shirt", and similar constructions, but we just don't normally say "black-skinned person".

In these politically-correct times, it is popular in some circles to use the wildly inaccurate "African-American". I say inaccurate because the term is used to describe people with black skin and not necessarily Americans who came from Africa. A white person who was born in Africa and moved to America is not called African-American. (https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/northamerica/usa/1452762/White-boy-suspended-for-claiming-African-prize.html) More strangely, Americans sometimes call black people in other parts of the world, who have never even been to America, "African-Americans".

Comment: Also note that it's far more common to say "black person" than any of the options in the question.